# Auto check Create account field in Woocommerce Checkout Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, registration

I am using woocommerce for a wordpress site and I would like for users to create an account during the checkout process when entering in payment details. Normally there is checkbox option that users must physically click to make an account.

Is there some implementation that can have this "create an account" box pre-checked and all users have to do is create a password.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJmYV.jpg)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeiW3.jpg)

Comment: you can edit the file inside woocommerce folder or on page load you can check the checkbox with jquery

Comment: you can check the checkbox on page load by using this : `jQuery('#checkboxid').prop('checked', true);`   inside footer.php of your theme

Answer (score 12):

## Checkout Require Create Account

**Checkbox Behavior**

Use the *woocommerce_create_account_default_checked* filter

`add_filter('woocommerce_create_account_default_checked' , function ($checked){
    return true;
});`

Place it in your theme or child theme's *functions.php*

**Alter Template**

Hide the checkbox and its label by overriding the woocommerce template.
You do so by copying the *form-billing.php* file to your theme's folder.

Add a hidden attribute to the input tag and delete the label tag.

`<input hidden class="..." ...`

Comment: Thank you! What exactly do you mean by add a hidden attribute to the input tag?

Comment: It's <p class="hidden …"

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Woocommerce--> settings --> account and privacy

Your account should have settings like this.
no need for development

Comment: But on certain themes the guest cannot enter the checkout before creating the account.

Answer (score 0):

there is a javascript changing the class from display:none to display:block which uses the class of the div. So rename this class which has no other styles
 to  or whatever
then the javascript has no class to handle. the div is displayed